# Including PHP script to change external CSS depending on month

Tags: php, html, css

I know you can change the CSS by changing the stylesheet files themselves and adding a .php extension but I need to find a way of using the PHP script on the index.php page to tell the header which stylesheet to put in to action depending on what month of the year it is.

My code at the moment is accurate to the best of my knowledge but for some reason it isn't being read in and implemented with any of the stylesheets.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php 
$date = getdate();
$month = $date["mon"];
$style = "style.css";
$autumn = "autumn.css";
$xmas = "christmas.css";

if($month == 10) 
{
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$autumn"/>';
}
elseif($month =="12")
{
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$xmas"/>';
}
else
{
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$style"/>';
}
?>
</head>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean it isnt being read? what is the outcome?

Comment: Maybe a path assigment. And check $month assigment and the " " usage. You arent checking for the same value in the if else statement

Comment: It's just a plain formatted HTML page with no stylesheet linked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use variables inside single quotation marks (`'`). That does not work, variables are only interpreted inside double quotation marks (`"`). Therefore, your code most proabably literally outputs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$autumn"/>
```

The necessary code line would be (adapt accordingly for the other lines, of course):

```
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"$autumn\"/>";
```

Alternatively, you could replace the escaped double quotation marks inside the HTML code with single quotation marks. Browsers don't really care about that (I'm not sure about the specification).

Comment: This is what I'm thinking, it's not taking in the variable of style.css but instead just reading it as $autumn.
I'll give the suggestion you said a go!

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks very much!!
Worked first time!

Comment: Great :-) Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Also, you might want to check out tools like Firebug or the developer console of your preferred browser. These tools allow you inspect the HTML source code of your site thoroughly, helping to spot problems such as this one.

Comment: That would be true if I was working on JavaScript but due to it being PHP server side I don't think that will work will it?
I've heard you can use Konodo but it seemed way too much effort therefore I just uploaded it to the server straight away instead & refresh.

Comment: Well, by inspecting the source code you would have noticed right away that the variable is not parsed, which might have helped you recognize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid some redundancy in your code, you could try an approach like this instead:

```
<?php 
$style = "style"; // Set the default stylesheet name
// then check for the special cases
$date = getdate();
if ($date["mon"] == 10) $style = 'autumn';
if ($date["mon"] == 12) $style = 'christmas';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $style; ?>.css"/>
</head>
```

This may also be easier to maintain than echoing out a bunch of HTML.

Comment: This seems like a more suitable approach, I might once it's completely finished change it to be more structured like this.
However I already have one solution for this but I suppose this solution may help others.
Thanks

Comment: @James no problem, just thought I'd offer an alternative suggestion. Please remember to accept the answer from TheWolf if it was the one solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a HTML5 doctype you don't need the type attribute on your link element. I thought I'd throw this approach into the pile:

```
switch( $month ) {
    case 10:
        $file = 'autumn.css';
    break;
    case 12:
        $file = 'christmas.css';
    break;
    default:
        $file = 'style.css';
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $file ?>">
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to try:

```
echo '<link rel=stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$style.'"/>';
```

Comment: Please explain why !!